# Entity Framework Code First Many-to-Many relationship and inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Forgive me if this question has been answered somewhere, I have been having a hard time finding a solution for this problem.

I am trying to set up EF Code First on an MVC4 Project. I have a User and Customer that both inherit from Person. I then have a Template object that has a Many-to-Many relationship with Customer and a One-to-Many relationship with User. Here is how I have it set up:

**MODELS**

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}

public class User : Person
{
    .... 
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    ....
}

public class Template
{
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTEXT**

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext()
        : base("name=ProjectDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions
            .Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Customers)
            .WithMany(x => x.Templates)
            .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("TemplateId")
                .MapRightKey("PersonId")
                .ToTable("TemplateCustomer")
            );
    }
}
```

If I remove the Person DBSet out of the context this works fine but sets up TPT inheritance. I would like to use TPH inheritance, but when I enable migrations with the Person DBSet in the context it chokes:

NavigationProperty 'Templates' is not valid. Type 'MvcProject.Models.Customer' of FromRole 'Template_Customers_Target' in AssociationType 'MvcProject.Models.Template_Customers' must exactly match with the type 'MvcProject.Models.Person' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot inherit *navigation properties* from a base entity. They always must be *declared* in the class the other end of the relationship is refering to.

- `Template.Customers` is refering to `Customer` (not to `Person`), hence the inverse navigation property `Templates` must be declared in `Customer` (not in `Person`)
- `Template.User` is refering to `User` (not to `Person`), hence the inverse navigation property `Templates` must be declared in `User` (not in `Person`)

So, basically you must move the `Templates` collection from `Person` into both derived classes:

```
public class Person
{
    // no Templates collection here
}

public class User : Person
{
    //... 
    public virtual List<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    //...
    public virtual List<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can define the two relationships with Fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Customers)
    .WithMany(c => c.Templates) // = Customer.Templates
    .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("TemplateId")
               .MapRightKey("PersonId")
               .ToTable("TemplateCustomer"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Templates) // = User.Templates
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HasMany selector to People:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
        .HasMany(x => x.People) // here
        .WithMany(x => x.Templates)
        .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("TemplateId")
            .MapRightKey("PersonId")
            .ToTable("TemplateCustomer")
        );
```

Comment: In order to do that I would have to change my list of customers to a list of Person. That would defeat the purpose, I need a many to many relationship with Template and Person.